Merging sprites to be used as a single tile
I am attempting to make a CompositeTile out of 4 sprites (one for each corner of the tile) that can be used as a single Tile within a Unity Tilemap. I assumed this would be straightforward, but after some fiddling, this is the best I've come up with so far.

Note: I adapted the following script using the Unity documentation as well as two YouTube tutorials. These are the links:

https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/Manual/tilemaps/tiles-for-tilemaps/scriptable-tiles/create-scriptable-tile.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FL0Jac5TAo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdTfgo9_hd8


Script: "CompositeTile.cs"
namespace Assets.Scripts.CustomTiles {
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    using UnityEditor;

#endif

    public class CompositeTile : Tile {
        [Header("Composite Tile Properties")]
        public Sprite[] cornerSprites;
        public bool merged = false;

        public Sprite MergedSprite {
            get {
                if(cornerSprites == null || cornerSprites.Length != 4) {
                    Debug.LogError("Four corner sprites are required to create a composite tile.");
                    return null;
                }

                var cornerWidth = (int)cornerSprites[0].textureRect.width;
                var cornerHeight = (int)cornerSprites[0].textureRect.height;
                var compositeWidth = cornerWidth * 2;
                var compositeHeight = cornerHeight * 2;

                var combinedTexture = new Texture2D(compositeWidth, compositeHeight);
                combinedTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
                combinedTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;

                // Loop through each pixel to combine the four corner textures
                for(int x = 0; x < compositeWidth; x++) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < compositeHeight; y++) {
                        // Determine which corner sprite to use based on the current pixel position
                        var cornerX = x < cornerWidth ? 0 : 1;
                        var cornerY = y < cornerHeight ? 1 : 0;
                        var id = cornerY * 2 + cornerX;

                        // Calculate the pixel position within the selected corner sprite
                        var pixelX = x % cornerWidth;
                        var pixelY = y % cornerHeight;

                        var currentCornerSprite = cornerSprites[id];
                        var currentCornerTexture = currentCornerSprite.texture;
                        var currentCornerRect = currentCornerSprite.textureRect;

                        // Get the color from the corresponding corner sprite
                        var pixelColor = currentCornerTexture.GetPixel(
                            (int)(currentCornerRect.x + pixelX),
                            (int)(currentCornerRect.y + pixelY)
                        );

                        // Set the pixel color in the combined texture
                        combinedTexture.SetPixel(x, y, pixelColor);
                    }
                }
                combinedTexture.Apply();

                // Create the final sprite from the combined texture
                var finalSprite = Sprite.Create(
                    combinedTexture,
                    //new Rect(0, 0, combinedTexture.width, combinedTexture.height),
                    new Rect(0, 0, compositeWidth, compositeHeight),
                    new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f)
                );
                finalSprite.name = "CompositeSprite";

                merged = true;
                return finalSprite;
            }
        }

        private bool CheckSprites(bool logging = false) {
            if(cornerSprites.Length != 4) {
                if(logging) Debug.LogError($"Invalid number of sprites.\n\t(length is: {cornerSprites.Length}, expected: 4)");
                return false;
            } else {
                if(cornerSprites[0] == null) {
                    if(logging) Debug.LogWarning("NW corner sprite not set.");
                    return false;
                }
                if(cornerSprites[1] == null) {
                    if(logging) Debug.LogWarning("NE corner sprite not set.");
                    return false;
                }
                if(cornerSprites[2] == null) {
                    if(logging) Debug.LogWarning("SW corner sprite not set.");
                    return false;
                }
                if(cornerSprites[3] == null) {
                    if(logging) Debug.LogWarning("SE corner sprite not set.");
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        public void MergeSprites(string msg = null, bool logging = false) {
            Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
            if(!merged) {
                if(CheckSprites(logging)) {
                    if(msg != null && logging) Debug.Log(msg);
                    sprite = MergedSprite; // Set the inherited sprite property directly
                }
            }
        }

        public override void RefreshTile(Vector3Int position, ITilemap tilemap) {
            base.RefreshTile(position, tilemap);
        }
        public override void GetTileData(Vector3Int position, ITilemap tilemap, ref TileData tileData) {
            MergeSprites("In -> GetTileData()", true);
            tileData.sprite = sprite; // Use the sprite property to set the TileData
            tileData.color = color;
            tileData.flags = flags;
            tileData.colliderType = colliderType;
        }
    }
}

I am getting some weird results. First, in the inspector, the sprite field says "Type mismatch". Second, when I drag the tile into a palette, the displayed tile is too small.
I have disabled my custom inspector to investigate but, because the engine doesn't throw any errors, I don't really have any more information.
My question is this:
How do I merge the four corners of a texture together correctly?
I would like these to be usable just like any other tile in Unity. My intent is to make several of these composite tiles which can then be used within a single rule tile. Later, I could potentially merge sprites of various lengths and widths.

Put simply, I can create four 32x32 primitive sprites for each tile type (road, rail, pipe, wire, etc.), and then use the four 16x16 corners of each sprite (making 16 total corners per tile type) to generate 12 more 32x32 tiles. I could then use these 12 generated tiles along with the 4 primitive tiles to produce a standard rule tile for the tile type.

Additionally, if I wanted to support flipping and rotating, I could potentially generate all sixteen 32x32 tiles from only three 16x16 "corner sprites".

In a perfect world, I would have a single spritesheet containing all the primitive tiles for the project sliced into 16x16 "corners" sprites. These would then get automatically stitched together into the other 12 composite tiles to generate a rule tile that can be dragged into a tile palette.

If your comments reflect strong requirements, you should edit your question to directly include them. Comments tend to be somewhat temporary and because long chains of comments are sometimes condensed by the system, it's easy for readers to miss details that are only presented in the comments.
